# Nombres calles en Japón en Mapbox Navigation Android

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, sdk

Tengo el SDK de Mapbox Navigation en Android

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/

y cuando se navega por Japón, hay nombres de calles que salen en inglés y no en japonés.

¿Alguna idea cómo resolver esto?

PD: Tengo la navegación con un navigationView.

Comment: Todas las calles salen en inglés?

Comment: Algunas en inglés y otras en japonés

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la documentación [Localización e internacionalización](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/localization/), aunque puedes definir el lenguaje como `.language('Japanese')` :

```
NavigationRoute.builder(context)
.accessToken(MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN)
.origin(origin, bearing, tolerance)
.destination(destination)
.language('Japanese')
.build();
```

No es posible por el momento ver en idioma Japones el nombre de las calles, **hasta el día (feb 2020) de hoy para el idioma Japones, únicamente son soportadas las instrucciones de voz ✅ pero no el lenguaje en la Interfaz de usuario —** .